# Failed to show Xcode notification due to the osascript while building the app

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, xcode

Unable to build my app suddenly. This is the error which I got after running the caused by:

```
 script error: osascript: no such component "JavaScript".
continuing in background.

       Error: Failed to display Xcode notification
          caused by: script error: osascript: no such component "JavaScript".

        /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dvcafjcjvuogulagizfflouagntd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/Script-00199139199199133.sh: line 5: debug]: command not found
```

Comment: What is the script, and how are you running it?

Comment: The script is upload debug symbols to sentry in build phases of my Xcode and Bundle react-native code and images script. export SENTRY_PROPERTIES=sentry.properties
../node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli upload-dsym
export SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=[info|debug].                                                                             Note: If I remove the scripts related to the sentry it works fine.(Failed to show the upload debug symbols notification)